# How to get rid of the cHash with routing enhancers?

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to get rifd of the cHash get parameter when using routing enhancers with custom extension.

The TYPO3 docs/changelog assume that this is possible:

> If you really have the requirement to never have a cHash argument, 
>   ensure that all placeholders are having strict definitions on what 
>   could be the result of the page segment ...

But what exactly does **strict definitions** mean.

This is my routing configuration:

```
routeEnhancers:
  ExecutiveSearchResultList:
    type: Extbase
    extension: executivesearch
    plugin: searchresultlist
    routes:
        - { routePath: '/list/{page}', _controller: 'Search::searchResultList', _arguments: {'page': 'page'} }
    defaultController: 'Search::searchResultList'
    defaults:
      page: '1'
      action: 'searchResultList'
      controller: 'Search'
    requirements:
      page: '\d+'
```

the result is

```
/path/to/my-page/list/1?cHash=6cd242916809d29b799debe824b37fcd
```

I also have a routing for tx_news that works fine do not append a cHash:

```
NewsPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: news
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/list/{page}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
      - { routePath: '/tag/{tag_name}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'tag_name': 'overwriteDemand/tags'}}
      - { routePath: '/news/{news_title}', _controller: 'News::detail', _arguments: {'news_title': 'news'} }
      - { routePath: '/archive/{year}/{month}', _controller: 'News::archive' }
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    aspects:
      news_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_news'
        routeFieldName: 'path_segment'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    requirements:
      page: '\d+'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53054351/923560 provides a workaround by using a mapper which returns the same value as provided from the route. It makes the cHash disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My workaround was a StaticRangeMapper.

Hint: 1000 is currently the maximum in the TYPO3 core.

```
  NewsPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 56
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/list/{page}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
      - routePath: '/detail/{news_title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news_title: news
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    requirements:
      page: \d+
    aspects:
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '1000'
      news_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But, as you wrote, it is a workaound not a solution.

Comment: Its only applicable if you have numeric values from 1...1000. But maybe the magic is to jaust add a mapper to the configuration. But in some cases i can not use one of the standard mappers, maybe i have to write a custom mapper, just to get rid of the cHash parameter.

Comment: Of course, you're right. If you need an example for a custom aspect, look here: https://gist.github.com/wazum/e5862338fbc4466bac8c66bf11efdf9e

Comment: When all Placeholders have an aspect configuration, then the chash disappears. I added a custom Mapper that does nothing, just for the case when i actually does not need one.